# Download a Visual Studio 2010 extension and use it offline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have downloaded an extension (format: vsix) .
How can i install it on Microsoft visual studio 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.vsix extensions are installed by vsixinstaller.exe. Normally it is run automatically when you double click the .vsix file. You can locate the installer in a path like "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe".